# What is the best solution to get common string in two List<string>

Tags: c#

As the title said, I have configured some ways to get the result(common string in two List), but I am looking for more **efficient** way to implement it.

```
List<String> x = new List<String>() { "hello", "world", "apple", "123" ,"big"};//maybe a lot
List<String> y = new List<String>() {"ok", "hello", "earth", "bi","pear", "123" };
var IntersectResult = Intersect(x, y);
```

My two ways:

```
String[] Intersect(List<String> a, List<String> b)
{
    var result = a.Intersect(b).ToArray();
    return result;
}

String[] Intersect(List<String> a, List<String> b)
{

        var data = new List<String>();

        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            if (b.Contains(item))
            {
                data.Add(item);
            }
        }
        var result = data.ToArray();
        return result;
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is your benchmark for "more efficient"? What is "bad" about what you've posted?

Comment: @Selvin if the OP meant "common items" yes, and the answer would be trivial - `Enumerable.Intersect` or use a `HashSet` to accelerate the that operation. Although I think `Intersect` builds a HashSet of the left enumerable

Comment: @Selvin Enumerable.Intersect already uses a set

Comment: @gunr2171 more faster maybe, since using `foreach` is the most inefficient  way.

Comment: @Ryan foreach isn't inefficient. It's the double foreach that's slow

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos hi,does that mean Enumerable.Intersect is already a good way?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think it is...and there must exist other better ways...

Comment: "does that mean Enumerable.Intersect is already a good way?" Why not try it out? Just **measure** and compare to your current solution.

Comment: @HimBromBeere if you see my code,I have used two ways and one is `Enumerable.Intersect` already.I am just asking whether there are better ways or it is the best way for two List<string> with large data

Comment: @Ryan for what? For general set operations, yes. That's not the most efficient way to work for specialized cases, eg if both lists are ordered, there's no need to create a set, you can walk both lists at the same time until you find identical items. If you `a5`>`b5` you know you aren't going to find b1-b5 in the `A` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is how to find the common *items*, you can use [Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netcore-3.1). Internally, it [creates a Set](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,ae06318d1f5fb355) with the second enumerable's items to accelerate the set operation.

```
var common=a.Intersect(b);
```

That's generally efficient but *doesn't* take advantage of eg the possible ordering of the two lists, which would allow walking along both lists just once.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine or measure the actual efficiency, you need to provide some sample data to work with as input.

Depending on the number of items, it might for example be faster to sort the lists and put the strings into some kind of sets.

I recommend you to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for tracking the performance of your methods instead of guessing or ask someone else to do the guessing for you.

The library is adopted by 4500+ projects including .NET Runtime and supported by the .NET Foundation.

Comment: This does not provide an **answer**, just some comments that ask for clarity, doesn´t it?

Comment: Clarity? The question is pretty clear to me. The bottom line is: if you really want to know which method is faster, then measure them.